# SQL Server Blocking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, profiler, blocking, trace

My production SQL Server 2008 R2 goes down from morning 4:00 am to 5:00 am.

I checked the SQL Server performance using grafana and found out that blocking happened between 4:00 am to 5:00 am.

It behaves normally after 5 am.I checked the jobs running,backups everything which runs overnight.But all those happens before 4 am.

I created a SQL Server Profiler trace job to run, but it is creating multiple trace files and it will bring down the production server if I did that.

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I couldn't find extended event under management. How will I know what is happening between 4 am to 5 am?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Check Windows Event log as well. When your SQL Server is down no event is logged.

Answer (score 0):

> How will I know what is happening between 4 am to 5 am?

EXtended events blocked process is not available in 2008 R2..so you could create some custom script  like below and run this through  a sql agent for every 5 mins and insert into some table

```
select rq.session_id,rq.status,rq.command,rq.wait_type,rq.last_wait_type,rq.wait_time,rq.wait_resource,
rq.blocking_session_id,
blocked.text  as 'blocked',
blocking.text as 'blockedby'
 from
sys.dm_exec_requests rq
join
sys.dm_exec_connections cn
on cn.session_id=rq.blocking_session_id
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(rq.sql_handle) blocked
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cn.most_recent_sql_handle) blocking
```

**References:**
http://www.chilledsql.com/welcome/tip_category_dmvqueries/tip_detail_dmvqueries_getblockingprocesses